# Save response body from Drive API to PHPword document

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-drive-api, drive, phpword

I have an app am developing. I have been using Drive API but am stuck.Am retrieving the response body from a google doc as folows

```
function GetDocumentBody($file) {
    $downloadUrls =  $this->drive_services->files->get($file)->getExportLinks();
    $downloadUrl=$downloadUrls['application/pdf'];

  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $this->drive_services->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {

        //var_dump($httpRequest->getResponseBody());die();
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
```

}

This is my controllers

```
 function GetDocumentBody(){
    $this->cloneJob($this->driverestapis_model->downloadFile('1untELR1y30mqu61X6lHSme3VCgbaIOeF0XxMy-b0sG4'));
}

function cloneJob($data){
    // Template processor instance creation
    echo date('H:i:s'), ' Creating new TemplateProcessor instance...';
    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('BULK/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx');


    //data
    $templateProcessor->setValue('data',htmlspecialchars($data));

    echo date('H:i:s'), ' Saving the result document...';
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('BULK/Sample_08_TemplateCloneRow.docx');

    //echo getEndingNotes(array('Word2007' => 'docx'));
}
```

After pulling the response body displays

> .PK.<[Gword/footer1.xml�V�N�0�������Э���/hU��8��x�Mc����;έ� ����C����3�����g%g[N���Ә̸f&�H��o�'d�<��F����#�W�.w�

what am i doing wrong

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I need to create a document from the response or alternatively get the data and put it to a document template

Comment: so in you code you are requesting for the document as pdf, and the result you are getting looks consistent. you would need to use pdf reader to actually see the information.  Have you tried using a different export link like: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" for get the document as docx?

Comment: Thank you @Gerardo from your comment i figured out this is what i was missing `file_put_contents($path,$httpRequest->getResponseBody());` I spent a whole day trying to figure out what's the issue. silly me